# Developing GUIs for Windows Embedded Compact 2013

Tags: javascript, v8, windows-embedded-compact, windows-embedded

We are currently evaluating Visual Studio as the IDE to develop embedded applications for Windows CE 2013.

Understandably having access to a large variety of widgets (either open or commercial) would be preferable to help us speed up GUI development and enrich it with the functionality we need.

The Javascript community for example offers this, and it would be great to be able to drag&drop js widgets while designing a GUI with VS, and then compile the code to target Windows CE2013.

Apache Cordova takes exactly this approach but it does not seem to support Javascript to Windows CE2013 compilation.

Qt does support WCE2013, which would allow us to add the Qt range of widgets to our toolset. Yet it is far from the wealth of options in the javascript universe.

Any suggestions? Is there a WCE2013 of a Cordova-like tool? Or alternatively a wrapping code to show javascript/html/css powered GUI and hook it Windows native C++ back-end code to actually do the work in response to user's interaction?

Comment: It sounds like you could use a [webkit browser](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=windows%20ce%202013%20webkit%20browser&rct=j).

Comment: Using a browser in kiosk mode could be the way to go to render the GUI. Apart from zetakey's port to Windows CE2013 I haven't found many websit alternatives. But will keep searching. Thanks!

Comment: On further research, it now seems that the cost of the Zetakey webkit-based browser for WCE2013 ($50 to $99 per device, depending on the type of commercial license purchased) makes this solution unfeasible for our devices. Yet running a webkit or V8 engine on WCE2013 to render the GUI still seems like a technically good solution, if only we could find a browser for WCE2013...